# Is it possible to change the multi index to normal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

So I have a data-set with for 4 IDs each id has 70 values, present and absent values. I counted the number of values of present and absent with the following code

```
df=pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID",'status'], values=["Sem1"], aggfunc=[len]).reset_index() 
df['ID'] = df['ID'].mask(df['ID'].duplicated(), '') 
df
  ID         Status      len
                         Sem1
 4234        Present     45
             Absent      25
 4235        Present     40
             Absent      30
 4236        Present     35
             Absent      35
 4237        Present     50
             Absent      20

 In: df.columns
 Out:ultiIndex(levels=[['len', 'status', 'ID'], ['sem1', '']],
       labels=[[2, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]])
```

I need to take the columns seperately to be added to two different data frames
Is there any way to take the columns separately ?
Also, need to know if it can be changed into the following data-set?

```
  ID         Status      Sem1
 4234        Present     45
             Absent      25
 4235        Present     40
             Absent      30
 4236        Present     35
             Absent      35
 4237        Present     50
             Absent      20
In:df.columns
Out:Index(['ID', 'Status','Sem1'], dtype='object')
```

Can this be done from the from the previos data-set

Comment: How working `df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).mean()` ?

Comment: yeah,if  I dont reset it my df.columns is OUT:MultiIndex(levels=[['mean', 'ID'], ['Sem1', 'Sem2', '']],
           labels=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])

Comment: Does it affect the answer?

Comment: No, it should remove `MultiIndex`, but not sure, so ask in comment.

Comment: In:df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).mean()                                     
Out: cannot insert ID, already exists

Comment: What is input DataFrame? I cannot simulate your problem.

Comment: I gave the wrong data frame sorry I am changing it now

Comment: @jezrael sorry  for my negligence

Comment: No problem, answer was edited. Please check it. also `len` was changed to `size`, because faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172474/discussion-between-san-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me your solution working nice.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sem1':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'Sem2':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'ID':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   Sem1  Sem2 ID
0     1     5  a
1     3     3  a
2     5     6  a
3     7     9  b
4     1     2  b
5     0     4  b

df1 = df.groupby('ID').mean().reset_index()
print (df1)
  ID      Sem1      Sem2
0  a  3.000000  4.666667
1  b  2.666667  5.000000
```

EDIT:

Remove `[]`:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["ID",'status'], values="Sem1", aggfunc='size').reset_index()
```